# help with understanding mail logs

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

I am trying to get sendmail to work with aws.   Using [this](http://lookingoutforpotholes.blogspot.com/2011/07/sendmail-relay-and-ses.html) additional info as well as the [amazon sendmail setup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?IntegratingWithServer.Sendmail.html) instructions I can successfully send mail from the command line.

When I try to send it through my app I get the following in my mail log and no mails are received.

Can anyone let me know what this means?  I am not sure how to t/s the problem or where to go from here.

```
sendmail[20162]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@01:00:00
sm-msp-queue[20170]: starting daemon (8.14.4): queueing@01:00:00
sendmail[20174]: kVR020174: From:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses
sendmail[20174]: kVR020174: Reply-To:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses
sendmail[20174]: kVR020174: from=apache, size=150, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201109140952.kVR020174@ip-....ec2.internal>, relay=apache@localhost
sendmail[20175]: kK5020175: from=<apache@ip-....ec2.internal>, size=452, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201109140952.kVR020174@ip-....ec2.internal>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [1$
sendmail[20174]: kVR020174: to='myemail@mydomain.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30150, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (kK5020$
sendmail[20174]: kVR020174: kVS020174: DSN: Reply-To:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses
sendmail[20175]: kK7020175: from=<>, size=2130, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201109140952.kVS020174@ip-....ec2.internal>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
sendmail[20174]: kVS020174: to=apache, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31174, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (kK7020175 Message accepted for delivery)
sendmail[20179]: kK7020175: to=root, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=32360, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
sendmail[20177]: kK5020175: to=<myemail@mydomain.comm>, ctladdr=<apache@ip-....ec2.internal> (48/48), delay=00:00:11, xdelay=00:00:11, mailer=aws-email, pri=120452, relay=mydomain.$
sendmail[20177]: kK5020175: p8E9qVK5020177: DSN: unknown mailer error 32
sendmail[20177]: qVK5020177: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31723, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

**EDIT ADDITIONAL INFO**

sendmail.cf [per aws config] or sendmail.mc [per other config option]

```
Maws-email, P=/opt/aws/ses/ses-send-email.pl, F=mDFMuXn, U=mailuser, 
        S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=EnvToSMTP, A=ses-send-email.pl -r -k /opt/aws
        /aws-credentials -e https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com   -f $f $u
```

Added mailuser

/etc/passwd

```
mailuser:*:12345:12345: mailuser:/no/where:/no/shell
```

/etc/group

```
mailuser:*:12345:
```

Comment: I assume you did put your credentials in /opt/aws/aws-credentials?

Comment: yes they are in there, like I said I can send from command line fine using those same credentials

Comment: haven't completely given up on this yet but attempting to use postfix as an alternative at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well took a different road here.  Using PostFix instead.

Answer (score 0):

The information can be found in the unkown mailer error 32 line. This means that something went wrong with the local mailer (defined on a M line in the sendmail configuration) and that the error is not in the range of known errors (64-78)

My guess is that you haven't properly set up the mail forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is new ground for me (Sendmail).  I am not sure if you familiar with Sendmail on AWS but I included the two links to the docs I used for setup.  Following those to configure my server I am not sure what I am missing or how to t/s from there.  Any tips on what to look for to verify mail fowarding?

Comment: untill you post your sendmail.mc/sendmail.cf file (the relevant lines like Maws-email) there's nothing someone can do but guess

Comment: Ok added in bottom of original question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but it might help someone who sees this error. 
You need to verify both your sender and recipient's e-mail address on Amazon SES if you are using non-production mode. Once this is verified, it is helpful if you put the verified address in sendmail-cf where you specify the path to the executable,

```
Maws-email, P=/opt/aws/ses/ses-send-email.pl, F=mDFMuXn, U=mailuser, 
S=EnvFromSMTP/HdrFromSMTP, R=EnvToSMTP, A=ses-send-email.pl -r -k /opt/aws
/aws-credentials -e https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -f verified_email@example.com $u
```